# "The resources at was blocked by Safe Browsing" issue in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, security, firefox

I have a WordPress website which is working fine in Chrome but in the Mozilla Firefox browser it shows `The resource at was blocked by Safe Browsing`. Here's my site URL if anybody can help to out this.

Site URL:
http://startlivingright.net

Comment: Add https and check this https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/821302a2-5b1d-4ecd-bae3-2ef6713c8155

Comment: https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/startlivingright.net

Answer (score 0):

The Safe Browsing feature is part of Google's network, which they use to identify websites which may have come under attack, appear malicious/fraudulent etc.

e.g. when I visit the link you attached:
[image: "Deceptive Site" Warning on Google]

You likely have content on the site which is dangerous, ads which are misleading etc.

See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249?hl=en&ref_topic=4596795 for more information.